# Where does Mac FileZilla cache host when using SFTP?

Tags: macos, ssh, cache, filezilla

I have used Filezilla on Mac to connect to my linux server over SSH and when prompted accepted and cached the server key signiture. Where does Mac Filezilla cache this as I want to clear it?

Mac OSX answers only please

Answer (score 3):

I've found it, for OSx Mavericks its under: ~/.putty/sshhostkeys